# Length of string does not tally with string in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How is it possible to have first.length equal 8 and first contains ",,,,,,,"(7characters) in node.js.

```
var express=require('express')
var app=express()
app.get('/',function(req,res)
{
    if(req.query.first)
    {
        if(req.query.first.length==8&&req.query.first==",,,,,,,")
        {
        res.send(result);
        return;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you need `,,,,,,,` as the first 7 character so that you can accept `,,,,,,,z` , `,,,,,,,1` and so on?

Comment: are you saying that this is returning as true somehow?

Comment: [,,,,,,,]==",,,,,,,"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `req.query.first.length === 8 && req.query.first.substring(0, req.query.first.length - 1) === ',,,,,,,'` as your condition so that your code becomes:

```
var express=require('express')
var app=express()
app.get('/',function(req,res)
  {
    if(req.query.first){
      var firstVal = req.query.first;
      if(firstVal.length === 8 && firstVal.substring(0, firstVal.length - 1) === ',,,,,,,'){
        res.send(result);
        return;
      }
    }
});
```

Here is a sample example of that:

```js
var str = ',,,,,,,1';
if(str.length === 8 && str.substring(0, str.length - 1) === ',,,,,,,'){
  console.log('matched');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `startsWith` function

```
if( req.query.first.length == 8 && req.query.first.startsWith(',,,,,,,') )
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be few reasons why a string length doesn't coincide the number of characters in JavaScript:

1. There are invisible characters in the string, e.g. [invisible times](https://unicode-table.com/en/2062/), [invisible separator](https://unicode-table.com/en/2063/).
2. There are characters that require more then 2 bytes. In JavaScripts strings use 2 bytes to encode a character. If a symbol UTF-8 encoding requires more then 2 bytes, JavaScript will use 2 characters (4 bytes) to store it and the length of this symbol will be 2, e.g. `''.length == 2`.